# How to get dats from Input?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have input element:

```
@Input() bObj: any;
```

When I try to get property `this.bObj.objectareacollection`:

```
   ngOnChanges() {
    this.administrativeArea = this.bObj.objectareacollection.reduce(function (
      accumulator,
      currentValue
    ) {
      accumulator.push(currentValue.objectarea);
      return accumulator;
    },
    []);

    console.log(this.administrativeArea);
  }
```

Why I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'objectareacollection' of undefined
```

Parent component:

```
export class BuildingObjectDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  public objectDetails: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .pipe(
        pluck("objid"),
        tap((objid: string) => {
          this.parametersService.findbyobjectidlatestFilter.parameters.objectid = objid;
        }),
        switchMap(() =>
          this.constructionObjectsDataService.findbyobjectidlatest()
        )
      )
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.objectDetails = response.reestrobject;
      });
  }
}
```

Template parent is:

```
<app-building-object-details-primary [bObj]='objectDetails' id="Primary">
</app-building-object-details-primary>
```

Comment: need more information. how objectareacollection array looks like

Comment: It looks like: `objectareacollection: [{objectarea: "GOО"}]`

Comment: That seems wrong, you defined it as type and not assigned as value. replace : with =

Comment: See my updated question

Comment: update your question with complete code related to this functionality

Comment: Done, look it again

Comment: from where bObj is coming. you are not assigning any value to it.

Comment: Comes from `@Input() bObj: any;`, first time it is undefined, then it has data

Comment: If first time it is `undefined` how it is updating data?

Comment: Could I use pipe to extract value?

Comment: You need to check in `ngOnChanges` whether your `input` is updating or not. Or best way in your parent component put `ngIf` for this component. like if this input data is present then only render this component

Comment: Can you show code of your parent component html? where you are declaring this component

Comment: Yes, see question

Comment: Its probably, first time your input is `undefined` and after some operations like getting data from API input is updated. so need to put check for undefined

Comment: Yes, you are right, see my parent component please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to solve this error

**1) Render component only if input is present**

If your child component is completely dependent on this `input` value, and your `objectDetails` of parent component is updating after some time (i.e. getting data from API) then you can check it with `ngIf`

Like in your parent component

```
 <app-building-object-details-primary *ngIf="objectDetails" [bObj]='objectDetails' id="Primary">
```

**2) Check for `undefined` value for first instance**

In your child component

```
if (this.bObj) {
   this.administrativeArea = this.bObj.objectareacollection.reduce(function (
```

Whichever suits you the best

Answer (score 0):

> You are accessing the input value in wrong way. Try below code.

```
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.bObj.currentValue){
           let currentInputValue = changes.bObj.currentValue;
           this.administrativeArea = currentInputValue.objectareacollection.reduce(function (
      accumulator,
      currentValue
    ) {
      accumulator.push(currentValue.objectarea);
      return accumulator;
    },
    []);
    }


    console.log(this.administrativeArea);
  }
```